# Gatsby hybrid app - Issues with sub routing on a page which is built using a template in `createPage`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, gatsby, reach-router

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that my site contains around 25k pages built from this template. The answer from Derek Nguyen will work for smaller sites with a small amount of pages, but when this is scaled up the `matchPath` data is stored in the JS, resulting in massive bundle sizes. (Around 3.1mb for me!)

### The Challenge

I need to create a page using `createPage` which contains a sub-routing system in which the default route is built to static HTML, but any other routes are client-only.

### The Problem

I have a template component used for static HTML generation in the `createPage` method, but also a component in the `pages/` directory used to assign a `matchPath` to for the client-only routes.

On the latest version of Gatsby, the template component renders for the default route, but then the "page" component renders for the client-only ones, leading to full page re-renders when I only want the sub-route to render, as there is data in the parent route which needs to persist.

It seems wrong in my head to have two components with two routers in, but I can't think of any other way to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

Here is an example of my routing set up:

Template used for `createPage`

```
<Router>
  <ContainerComponent
     path={urlFromGraphQL}
  >
    <DefaultRoute
      default
    />
  </ContainerComponent>
</Router>
```

Client only component in `/pages`

```
<Router>
  <ContainerComponent
     path="/some-route/:slug/:id"
  >
    <DefaultRoute
      default
    />
    <SecondTabRoute
      path="second-tab-route"
    />
    <ThirdTabRoute
      path="third-tab-route"
    />
  </ContainerComponent>
</Router>
```

I have also replicated the behaviour in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-hkhbb). Make sure to go to https://hkhbb.sse.codesandbox.io/test/foo/bar to see the correct output.

I have created an [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16250) in github about this but have yet to have a reply.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

It looks like you're mixing statically generated page & dynamic page, i.e you're both generating a page at `/test/foo/bar` while matching `test/:param1/:param2` in `test.js`.

Statically generated pages will have higher specificity than dynamic pages, so Gatsby thinks `test/foo/bar` & `test/foo/bar/second-route` are 2 different pages instead of being 2 dynamic routes from the same static page.

**Potential solution**

What you'd need to do in this case is to make *both* `/test` & `/test/foo/bar` root page for dynamic routes. This way, a random match such as `/test/one/two` will be a dynamic route of `/test`; while `/test/foo/bar/second-route` will be a dynamic route of `/test/foo/bar`.

Since you've already creating `/test/foo/bar` programmatically, making it a root for dynamic pages is trivial:

```js
  // gatsby-node.js
  exports.createPages = async ({ actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
    const pathFromGraphQL = "/test/foo/bar"

    createPage({
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/template.js`),
      context: {
        url: pathFromGraphQL,
      },
      path: pathFromGraphQL,
+     matchPath: `${pathFromGraphQL}/*`,
    })
  }
```

The issue is now that the 'template.js' is not exactly a template anymore, it'd have to contain components & routes that are specific to `test/foo/bar`. Depending on your requirements this could be a show stopper, or it could be somehow circumvented.

I edit your fork a little bit to demonstrate this; beside the code change above code from `pages/test.js` is moved to `templates/template.js` & I add a dummy component for `pages/test.js` to show that it'll still handle other dynamic route:

- [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-3ff8e?fontsize=14)
- [random match (test/one/two)](https://3ff8e.sse.codesandbox.io/test/one/two)
- [test/foo/bar match](https://3ff8e.sse.codesandbox.io/test/foo/bar)

Also, if you decide to do this, be aware of this ['wont-fix' bug](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15398).

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that in my case, we generate 25k pages based from these templates. I went down that route of supplying a `matchPath` directly in the `createPage` options, and you're right it works fine. The only issue is that since Gatsby v2.9.0, an array containing `matchPath` data is bundled into the JS. This results in a massive JS bundle for sites with a large amount of pages. I initially created an [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14954) about this, which led onto the one I currently have open!

Comment: wow yeah, this won't help you then :/I'll watch the issue & see if another solution come up